# Question activity filters: feature or bug?

Tags: bug

I've noted an interesting difference between the two filters on the main page.

The main set of filters on the same level as the **Genealogy and Family History** header are:  Questions  Tags  Users Badges Unanswered  Ask Question

Underneath that, if you are viewing the list of questions on the main page, across from where it says **All Questions** the choices are: newest frequent votes active unanswered

If you choose "unanswered" from the selections on the banner, you get a list of questions where the number of answers = 0.

If you choose "unanswered" from the "all questions" row, the top result is a question with an answer (disclaimer: answered by me, but I'm not fishing for upvotes here):

[What does “Containing by Estimation Seven Days' Work” mean in 1810 Land Auction advertisement?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/7825/1006)

Is this a feature, or a bug?  Does the question still rate as 'unanswered' on the main page because the only answer so far has zero upvotes?

Answer (score 2):

It is a feature (not bug) and the graphics below will illustrate why:

[image]

---

[image]

Note how the discrepancy in count is explained by the red text in the top graphic.

Personally, I think the top Unanswered button might be better named something else to avoid confusion - perhaps Priority because we do not want good questions to go unanswered; good answers to go un-upvoted and/or unaccepted; and any others showing up there going uncommented, unedited or unclosed.

Today I have posted a feature request on Meta SE for https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247662/changing-name-of-first-unanswered-button-to-perhaps-priority

Also, if it is the lower graphic showing a slightly higher count than the top one then that is explained in the answer to [Discrepancy in the number of "questions with no accepted or upvoted answers"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244340/discrepancy-in-the-number-of-questions-with-no-accepted-or-upvoted-answers) on Meta SE.

Comment: Interesting.  Using Iceweasel 32.0.3 (a branded variant of Firefox) and choosing *Questions* from the top bar and *unanswered* on the lower filter, I get 45 questions with no explanatory red text. NoScript is set to allow all from stackexchange.com and to allow all this page.